# Finding a specific value in a non-sorted xml file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, sax

Using java, I'm trying to find the most recent highest entry number.   This entry needs to specify a specific type.   From there it needs to pull the value.

Here's what the xml looks like

```
<XmlFile>
   <data_item>
        <data_report>
            <type>My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>12</entry_number>                
            <value>1234</value>
        </data_report>
        <data_report>
            <type>My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>9</entry_number>                
            <value>11234</value>
        </data_report>
   </data_item>
   <data_item>
      <data_report>
             <type>My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>17</entry_number>                
            <value>112354</value>
      </data_report>
      <data_report>
             <type>Not_My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>122</entry_number>                
            <value>11234</value>
      </data_report>
   </data_item>
</XmlFile>
```

So the takeaways are the data I need needs to be of "My_Type" it can be in ANY data_item, but it needs to find the maximum interval out of all items of my_type, the pull the value only.

I have tried doing this with Xpath, but I couldn't quite get it to work.   In this case the third data report (in the second data item) would be the one I'm after since it has the highest entry number while being "My Type" so I would want the program to grab the number 112354 for me.

Is there some way to do this using Xpath?    The file that I'm trying to get this to work on is MUCH larger than this, but Xpath seems like the easiest option, I'm not opposed to DOM or SAX if those are better suited.

Thanks!

Comment: for your sample xml file, whats the expected output?

Comment: There is no output, the xml file is the input into a java program, I'm merely trying to extract the 112354 from the xml based on the above criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max()` function is not available in XPath 1.0.

**A pure XPath expression that produces the wanted (of the first if there are more than one nodes with the wanted maximum property) value, is**:

```
   string(
      /*/*/*[type='My_Type'
           and
             not(/*/*/*[type='My_Type']/entry_number > entry_number)
            ][1]/value
          )
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "string(
      /*/*/*[type='My_Type'
           and
             not(/*/*/*[type='My_Type']/entry_number > entry_number)][1]/value
          )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<XmlFile>
    <data_item>
        <data_report>
            <type>My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>12</entry_number>
            <value>1234</value>
        </data_report>
        <data_report>
            <type>My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>9</entry_number>
            <value>11234</value>
        </data_report>
    </data_item>
    <data_item>
        <data_report>
            <type>My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>17</entry_number>
            <value>112354</value>
        </data_report>
        <data_report>
            <type>Not_My_Type</type>
            <entry_number>122</entry_number>
            <value>11234</value>
        </data_report>
    </data_item>
</XmlFile>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
112354
```

Comment: I actually ended up at something quite similar to this myself, my answer was:  //m:REPORT_DATA[not(//m:REPORT_DATA/m:INTERVAL_NUM > m:INTERVAL_NUM) and m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC']//m:VALUE/text()   (Note, my xml file was actually http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/f8930d5d-cd32-4fb6-9895-203d82d6ab82 that and not what I put above.  Most people get scared off by the caps / namespace.

Comment: Also:  This is a great answer and deserves more attention than it will likely get.

Comment: @Damien.Bell, You are welcome. This technique for finding maximum in a single XPath expression is well-known. It has quadratic time complexity and would be slow for long sequences. For long sequences, one can use an efficient XSLT 1.0 method for finding maximum.

Comment: Can you show me an instance where performance would be impacted by the method that I was using and back that up with numbers?  (Please don't take this as a challenge, I'm genuinely interested and want to know more about the topic at hand)  

Thanks!

Comment: @Damien.Bell, When you increase the number of `data_report` elements (of the wanted type) 10 times, the time to evaluate the expression increases 100 times -- just measure it -- say have first 20 elements and then make them 200 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Xpath expression.

```
max(//data_item/data_report[type = 'My_Type' and entry_number = max(//data_item/data_report[type = 'My_Type']/entry_number)]/value)
```

Comment: Would this traverse all the existing data_items?

Comment: @Damien.Bell Yes it traverse all the existing data_items. Also based on your comment, i have now changed the answer. Try this and let me know

Comment: I think this runs into the problem of not checking the entry_number for the highest one.

Comment: My actual string looks like this, which just doesn't seem like it will work out quite right:

Comment: max(//m:OASISReport/m:MessagePayload/m:RTO/m:REPORT_ITEM/m:REPORT_DATA[m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC']/m:VALUE/text()) As this would pull the maximum value, rather than the highest "interval" (which is another field under report_data) and then getting the value in that same report.

Comment: I'll try it with the new one, that's a hardcore xpath function

Comment: I tried that out and didn't have much luck, here was the xpath command I ended up using:  String XPathString = "max(//m:OASISReport/m:MessagePayload/m:RTO/m:REPORT_ITEM/m:REPORT_DATA[m:DATA_ITEM = 'LMP_PRC' and m:INTERVAL_NUM=max(//m:OASISReport/m:MessagePayload/m:RTO/m:REPORT_ITEM/m:REPORT_DATA/m:INTERVAL_NUM)/m:VALUE/text())";

Comment: For reference //m:OASISReport/m:MessagePayload/m:RTO/m:REPORT_ITEM/m:REPORT_DATA/ is where Interval_Num (which we've been calling entry number) and Value as DATA_ITEM (also called type above) live.

Comment: Added in the missing ] that I left out and I'm still getting null xpath issues

Comment: http://pastebin.com/55f8XMi1 is a link to the document that I'm trying this against.  LMP_PRC is the type, INTERVAL_NUM should be max.   VALUE should be grabbed on those conditions.... I'm fairly certain that it's possible with xpath but jeez is it difficult (not sure if live data would help you out)

Comment: the expression i gave works for the sample data you given. Try replacing with the actual node names you have. Good luck

Comment: I'm giving that a shot right now, I'll give it another go, I'm not sure why it isn't working then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18549/discussion-between-kaipa-m-sarma-and-damien-bell)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any automated way of doing this.  I would:
- parse the xml to create a list of DataReport objects (DOM will work just fine)
- create a comparator between DataReport objects
- order your list according to that comparator